# re.match in python to match pattern with string

Tags: python

I am trying to match `string` with `mypattern`, somehow I do not get correct result. Can you please point where am I wrong?

```
import re
mypattern = '_U_[R|S]_data.csv'
string =  'X003_U_R_data.csv'
re.match(mypattern, string)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches only *from the beginning of the string*. Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead to search the whole string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to compile the regex statement first. Then I do whatever kind of matching/searching I would like.

```
mypattern = re.compile(ur'_U_[R|S]_data.csv')
```

Then

```
re.search(mypattern, string)
```

Here's a great website for regex creation- https://regex101.com/#python

Comment: He doesn't have to compile it though. He can use re.search without compiling. Look: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end

Comment: You are correct sir. Stupid mistake on my part. I changed my wording of the answer.

Comment: https://regex101.com/#python. This Link was useful. Thanks

Comment: I believe what was wrong with his code was that there were no 'ur' flags to indicate Unicode and Raw string, so the []'s were literal rather than symbolic